# Series Solutions Near an Ordinary Point 5.2 #3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Question 3 of 5.2 in Boyce's *Differential Calculus* asks

a) Seek power series solutions around *x_0* and find the recurrence relation

b) Find the first four terms in *y1* and *y2*

c) Show that *y1* and *y2* are a fundamental set of solutions (through evaluating *W(y1,y1)(x0)*

d) Find the general term if possible in each solution

*y" - xy' - y = 0, x_0 = 1*

The textbook gives the answer to a) as *(n+2)a_n+2 - a_n+1 - a_n = 0* but I can't figure out for the life of me how I would distribute the *x = 1 + (x-1)* properly to get that answer.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer below is useful. Marking a correct answer helps order the StackExchange community. If you have any questions, get in touch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-(1-(x-1))y' - y = 0$$

$$y''-y'-(x-1)y' - y = 0$$

The goal is to center this solution around $x_o=1$, so we use power series in the form

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-1)^n$

$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n n(x-1)^{n-1} $

$\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} (n+1)(x-1)^{n}$

$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n n(n-1)(x-1)^{n-2} $

$\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)(x-1)^{n}$

$\ $

The trick above is to reindex your sums. This gives us a few forms of $y,y',y''$ to play with. To reindex, think "if I scroll my index *back by 1*, I need to set every occurrence of the index in the summand *ahead by 1*." Hence changing index $n=1$ to $n=0$ changes the term $n$ to $n+1$. We'll find that some of the above forms of $y,y',y''$ will be useful, while otherwise not so much. Carefully follow the choice of substitutions that will follow.

Remember, we want all the powers of $(x-1)$ to be the same. After substitutions, the differential equation becomes:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)(x-1)^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} (n+1)(x-1)^{n}$

$\ -(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n n(x-1)^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-1)^n = 0 $

$\ $

Okay, did you notice the sleight of hand? We used two *different forms for $y'$*. The second form has power $(x-1)^{n-1}$, but it can gobble up the $(x-1)$ in front of the summation to make it the desired power $n$.

Once we do that and collect terms, we find

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)- a_{n+1}(n+1)-  a_n](x-1)^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n n(x-1)^{n}= 0$

$\ $

Now we're close. We want all of our indices to be "on the same page." The left sum is at $n=0$ the right is at $n=1$. Here we *do not reindex. Rather, we just take the sum for $n=0$.*

$2a_2-a_1-a_0 + $

$\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)- a_{n+1}(n+1)-  a_n](x-1)^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n n(x-1)^{n}= 0$

$\ $

$2a_2-a_1-a_0 + $

$\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)- a_{n+1}(n+1)- (n+1) a_n](x-1)^{n}= 0$

$\ $

So the recurrence relation is

$$a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)- a_{n+1}(n+1)- (n+1) a_n = 0$$

$$a_{n+2}(n+2)- a_{n+1}- a_n = 0$$